# Enabling TSO (TCP Segmentation offloading) for double vlan interface

Tags: linux, tcp, interface, linux-kernel

I created double vlan interface in linux machine using following command.

ip link add link eth6 eth6.10 type vlan proto 802.1Q id 10
ip link add link eth6.10 eth6.10.20 type vlan proto 802.1ad id 20

I could find following segmentation

```
#ethtool -k eth6 |grep segmentation
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
     tx-tcp-segmentation: on
     tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
     tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]

#ethtool -k eth6.10 |grep segmentation
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
    tx-tcp-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]

#ethtool -k eth6.10.20 |grep segmentation
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
    tx-tcp-segmentation: off [requested on]
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [requested on]
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off [requested on]
generic-segmentation-offload: off [requested on]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]
```

I tried enabling TSO operation for interface eth6.10.20 but i receive following error.

#ethtool -K eth6.10.20 tso on

Could not change any device features

Please help me enabling with this feature.